# Red Hat Clustering Fencing fails

Tags: centos, redhat, vmware-esx, rhcs, fencing

I'm trying to demo (and learn) a Red Hat Cluster on ESXi 3.5 update2.I've set a shared fencing device with the info for my ESXi server. I try fencing a node from Luci, but it only tells me that fencing failed. Messages log has following agent "fence_vmware" reports: Unable to connec/login to fencing device. I checked and rechecked password and the connection properties.

Any ideas why this is happening. Is it possible to use ESXi as fencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible but ESXi's management interfaces might not respond quickly or reliably enough to make this as robust as it needs to be. There's some info on [this here](http://sources.redhat.com/cluster/wiki/VMware_FencingConfig) which seems to indicate that it's very much a work in progress but you may have something more supported that you are trying.

Since all you really need to do with Fencing is be able to trigger a VM reboot when certain conditions are met I don't see why it shouldn't work provided the fence scripts are sufficiently well written to be able to deal with the "latency" of the VCLI\VIX commands. One thing I have noticed with the various CLI tools is that authentication delays can be troublesome and may make this quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manually run the script? The output might be a clue as to why it fails